# Secure JPA binding in Play framework

Tags: security, jpa, binding, playframework

I have a page:

```
<input type="hidden" name="user.id" value="123" />
<input type="text" name="user.name" value="John" />
```

and an action:

```
public static void save(User user) {
    user.save();
}
```

Play loads the user entity from database by the user.id parameter, binds HTTP parameters to the object and the action saves it.

That is ok for trusted user like admin but not trusted user can change HTTP parameters to:

```
?user.id=456&user.name=John
```

and thus edit a different entity.

I check whether user has changed the user.id by putting user.id also to the session and then I validate its equality. This works fine since session is signed and can't be modified but how can I check easily many entities on the page – e.g. when doing a bulk update? Or just do it application wide by default?

I don't want to put 20 ids to the session and then check each id if it is equal to HTTP parameter.
One solution came to my mind. I would put a signed id as a token to each entity and check it during binding. How would you implement this?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand what you want is authentication and authorization.

Authentication tells you who the user is and you can pHk answer to do that or use the [secure module](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.3/secure)

If you want to manage authorization (what the user can do, in your case what object the user can update) I would recommend looking at the [security-permissions](https://github.com/lunatech-labs/Secure-Permissions-Play--module) module.

It is based on the secure module but the drools based rules give you all the flexibility you need.

Comment: Yes, I want to authorize that user sends me back same object (i.e. same id) I gave him to edit. Sure, I could check in the `save()` method that the bind User object is actually the one the user is permitted to edit. But if I want to bind and save a full graph of entities at once, I have to traverse the graph and check every entity. And this checking would be needed for every form and `save()` method. I am looking for more general solution, I'll try to describe it in an answer.

Comment: That will not work either because after the first save call hibernate cascade save/update will not call the playframework save! In that case you can use an hibernate eventListener that calls the security-permissions module.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to clarify my solution proposed at the end of my question which would solve it generally.

Each entity will have another field – a token – which is the entity id signed by the secure key. This token does not have to be stored in database but can be computed on the fly. When a edit page is rendered it includes the signed id in e.g. `__at` field:

```
<input type="hidden" name="user.id" value="123" />
<input type="hidden" name="user.__at" value="9e01f3c8...4ccba38b9" />
<input type="hidden" name="user.address.id" value="124" />
<input type="hidden" name="user.address.__at" value="83df099...4a276fc8" />
```

When these entities are being bound in controller it sings again the received id and compares it to the `__at` field. If these signed values are not same then it indicates the user has changed the id.

I am not an encryption expert and didn't look how Play session is signed but I guess it is similar. Do you think this mechanism could work?

Answer (score -1):

You can use checkAuthenticity method in a controller to check the authenticity of the form submitted.

In your server code you also have to check that the user as the rights to update theses entities. This can be done by adding a join to the user table in your jpa queries so you select not only on the object id but also on the user connected

Comment: checkAuthenticity checks only the authenticity token not modification of ids and it is intended to prevent [CSRF](http://wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery). Your second advice would solve it but it requires more coding. I am looking rather for application wide solution.

Answer (score -1):

You'll have to make sure that save can only be called by authenticated users. One way Play! allows you to do this is by using the `@Before` annotation. An example from the play documentation:

```
@Before(unless={"login", "authenticate"})
static void checkAuthenticated() {
    if(!session.contains("user")) {
        login();
    }
}
```

The `user` session attribute would then be put in the session **only** when the user has authenticated. Only authenticated users will be allowed to send HTTP requests to your `save()` route. Note in particular the `unless` and `only` annotation parameters.

The code above comes from the [OpenID example](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.3/libs#OpenID) in the Play! documentation. I have used this once and so far this seems to work perfectly.

Comment: I already have authentication mechanism in the application. But that would not solve the problem. User can sign up for free and even authenticated user is able to change the `user.id` parameter and thus edit entries of other users. I am trying to find a general solution where you can edit many entities at once and validate all its ids.